# Android input Stream doesn't receive any message

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I'm trying to receive data from Bluetooth which is connected to arduino ,but when I read from the input stream it keep giving me bytes=0 
this is my code for Bluetooth service :

```
package com.example.googlemapproject;

import android.app.Service;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.os.Message;
import android.os.Messenger;
import android.os.RemoteException;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.UUID;
import java.util.Vector;


public class BluetoothService extends Service {
    TextToSpeech txt_to_speech;

    private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;

    public static final String B_UUID = "00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb";


    public static final int STATE_NONE = 0;

    public static final int STATE_CONNECTING = 2;


    private ConnectBtThread mConnectThread;
    private static ConnectedBtThread mConnectedThread;

    private static Handler mHandler = null;
    public static int mState = STATE_NONE;

    public static BluetoothDevice sDevice = null;
    public Vector<Byte> packData = new Vector<>(2048);


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
    public void toast(String mess){
        Toast.makeText(this,mess,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        String deviceg = intent.getStringExtra("bluetooth_device");


        mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

        connectToDevice(deviceg);

        return START_STICKY;
    }
    private synchronized void connectToDevice(String macAddress){
        BluetoothDevice device = mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice("00:13:EF:00:E3:77");
        if (mState == STATE_CONNECTING){
            if (mConnectThread != null){
                mConnectThread.cancel();
                mConnectThread = null;
            }
        }
        if (mConnectedThread != null){
            mConnectedThread.cancel();
            mConnectedThread = null;
        }
        mConnectThread = new ConnectBtThread(device);
        toast("connecting");
        mConnectThread.start();
        setState(STATE_CONNECTING);
    }
    private void setState(int state){
        mState = state;
        if (mHandler != null){
            // mHandler.obtainMessage();
        }
    }
    public synchronized void stop(){
        setState(STATE_NONE);
        if (mConnectThread != null){
            mConnectThread.cancel();
            mConnectThread = null;
        }
        if (mConnectedThread != null){
            mConnectedThread.cancel();
            mConnectedThread = null;
        }
        if (mBluetoothAdapter != null){
            mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
        }

        stopSelf();
    }

    public void sendData(String message){
        if (mConnectedThread!= null){
            mConnectedThread.write(message.getBytes());
            toast("sent data");
        }else {
            Toast.makeText(BluetoothService.this,"Failed to send data",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean stopService(Intent name) {
        setState(STATE_NONE);

        if (mConnectThread != null){
            mConnectThread.cancel();
            mConnectThread = null;
        }

        if (mConnectedThread != null){
            mConnectedThread.cancel();
            mConnectedThread = null;
        }

        mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
        return super.stopService(name);
    }

/*private synchronized void connected(BluetoothSocket mmSocket){

    if (mConnectThread != null){
        mConnectThread.cancel();
        mConnectThread = null;
    }
    if (mConnectedThread != null){
        mConnectedThread.cancel();
        mConnectedThread = null;
    }

    mConnectedThread = new ConnectedBtThread(mmSocket);
    mConnectedThread.start();


    setState(STATE_CONNECTED);
}*/

    private class ConnectBtThread extends Thread{
        private final BluetoothSocket mSocket;
        private final BluetoothDevice mDevice;

        public ConnectBtThread(BluetoothDevice device){
            mDevice = device;
            BluetoothSocket socket = null;
            try {
                socket = device.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(UUID.fromString(B_UUID));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            mSocket = socket;

        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

            try {
                mSocket.connect();
                Log.d("service","connect thread run method (connected)");
                SharedPreferences pre = getSharedPreferences("BT_NAME",0);
                pre.edit().putString("bluetooth_connected",mDevice.getName()).apply();

            } catch (IOException e) {

                try {
                    mSocket.close();
                    Log.d("service","connect thread run method ( close function)");
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            //connected(mSocket);
            mConnectedThread = new ConnectedBtThread(mSocket);
            mConnectedThread.start();
        }

        public void cancel(){

            try {
                mSocket.close();
                Log.d("BT","connect thread cancel method");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private class ConnectedBtThread extends Thread{
        private final BluetoothSocket cSocket;
        private final InputStream inS;
        private final OutputStream outS;

        private byte[] buffer;

        public ConnectedBtThread(BluetoothSocket socket){
            cSocket = socket;
            InputStream tmpIn = null;
            OutputStream tmpOut = null;

            try {
                tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            try {
                tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();

                Log.d("BT","OUTPUT STREAM");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            inS = tmpIn;
            outS = tmpOut;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
          //  Looper.prepare();
            Log.d("BT","REading FROM IS");
            int bytesAvailable = 0;
            try {
                bytesAvailable = inS.available();
                Log.d("BT","REading FROM IS");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            byte[] buffer = new byte[bytesAvailable];
            int bytes;
            Log.d("BT","REading #BYTES");

            while (true) {
                try {try {
                    sleep(100);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


                    bytes = inS.read(buffer);
                    Log.d("BT",String.valueOf(bytes));
                    final String strReceived = new String(buffer, 0, bytes);
                   // Log.d("BT",strReceived);


            } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }}
         }


        private void cancel(){
            try {
                cSocket.close();
                Log.d("service","connected thread cancel method");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        this.stop();
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

I tried another app and the data from Bluetooth is received correctly so the problem is not in the Bluetooth,also I tried to put sleep while reading but it didn't work too

Comment: Too much code! Can you [edit] your question and trim this to a [mcve]? See also [ask].

Comment: @Robert I've edited it ,any help will be appreciated !

Comment: Your code continues after exceptions as though they hadn't happened. Don't write code like this. Code that depends on the success of code in a prior try block should be inside that try block.